# What is the difference between tensor[:] and tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

```py
import numpy as np
import time
features, labels = d2l.get_data_ch7()

def init_adam_states():
    v_w, v_b = torch.zeros((features.shape[1], 1),dtype=torch.float32), torch.zeros(1, dtype=torch.float32)
    s_w, s_b = torch.zeros((features.shape[1], 1),dtype=torch.float32), torch.zeros(1, dtype=torch.float32)
    return ((v_w, s_w), (v_b, s_b))

def adam(params, states, hyperparams):
    beta1, beta2, eps = 0.9, 0.999, 1e-6
    for p, (v, s) in zip(params, states):
        v[:] = beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data
        s = beta2 * s + (1 - beta2) * p.grad.data**2
        v_bias_corr = v / (1 - beta1 ** hyperparams['t'])
        s_bias_corr = s / (1 - beta2 ** hyperparams['t'])
        p.data -= hyperparams['lr'] * v_bias_corr / (torch.sqrt(s_bias_corr) + eps)
    hyperparams['t'] += 1

def train_ch7(optimizer_fn, states, hyperparams, features, labels, batch_size=10, num_epochs=2):
    # 初始化模型
    net, loss = d2l.linreg, d2l.squared_loss

    w = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(np.random.normal(0, 0.01, size=(features.shape[1], 1)), dtype=torch.float32),
                           requires_grad=True)
    b = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, dtype=torch.float32), requires_grad=True)

    def eval_loss():
        return loss(net(features, w, b), labels).mean().item()

    ls = [eval_loss()]
    data_iter = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(features, labels), batch_size, shuffle=True)

    for _ in range(num_epochs):
        start = time.time()
        print(w)
        print(b)
        for batch_i, (X, y) in enumerate(data_iter):
            l = loss(net(X, w, b), y).mean()  # 使⽤平均损失

            # 梯度清零
            if w.grad is not None:
                w.grad.data.zero_()
                b.grad.data.zero_()

            l.backward()
            optimizer_fn([w, b], states, hyperparams)  # 迭代模型参数
            if (batch_i + 1) * batch_size % 100 == 0:
                ls.append(eval_loss())  # 每100个样本记录下当前训练误差

    # 打印结果和作图
    print('loss: %f, %f sec per epoch' % (ls[-1], time.time() - start))
    d2l.set_figsize()
    d2l.plt.plot(np.linspace(0, num_epochs, len(ls)), ls)
    d2l.plt.xlabel('epoch')
    d2l.plt.ylabel('loss')
train_ch7(adam, init_adam_states(), {'lr': 0.01, 't': 1}, features, labels)
```

I want to implement the Adam algorithm in the follow code and I feel confused in the function named adam.

```
v = beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data
s = beta2 * s + (1 - beta2) * p.grad.data**2
```

when I use the follow code, the loss function curve is figure 1.
[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdHOU.png)

```
v[:] = beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data
s = beta2 * s + (1 - beta2) * p.grad.data**2
or
v = beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data
s[:] = beta2 * s + (1 - beta2) * p.grad.data**2
```

when I use the follow code, the loss function curve is figure 2.
[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEJCg.png)

```
v[:] = beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data
s[:] = beta2 * s + (1 - beta2) * p.grad.data**2
```

when I use the follow code, the loss function curve is figure 3.
[figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/671QF.png)

- The loss function curve in case 3 has always been smoother than that in case 1.
- The loss function curve in case 2 sometimes can't converge.

**Why is different?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question,

```
v = beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data
```

is an *out-of-place* operation. Remember that python variables are references to objects. By assigning a new value to variable `v`, the underlying object which `v` referred to before this assignment will **not** be changed. Instead the expression `beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data` results in a new tensor which is then referred to by `v`.

On the other hand

```
v[:] = beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data
```

is an *in-place* operation. After this operation `v` still refers to the same underlying object, and the elements of that tensor are modified and replaced with the values of the new tensor `beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data`.

---

Take a look at the following 3 lines to see why this matters

```
for p, (v, s) in zip(params, states):
    v[:] = beta1 * v + (1 - beta1) * p.grad.data
    s[:] = beta2 * s + (1 - beta2) * p.grad.data**2
```

`v` and `s` are actually referring to tensors which are stored in `states`. If we do *in-place* operations then the values in states are changed to reflect the value assigned to `v[:]` and `s[:]`.

If *out-of-place* operations are used then the values in `states` remain unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I still don’t understand another thing. I conducted some tests and output the values ​​of (v, s) and states. The results are as you said.  But why does the value of params change with the value of p? All of these variables are tensor.

Comment: Is it because the variables in params all calculate the gradient?

Comment: I understand the problem. The data calculation with the leaf of pytorch is an in-place operation. Thank you.